# error Use of unassigned local variable (switch) in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting the below mentioned error for my codes

```
 error Use of unassigned local variable (switch) in C# for strFavoriteColor
```

My codes:

```
private void lstData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strName;
        string strFavoriteColor;
        strName = lstData.Items[lstData.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        switch (strName)
        {
            case "Amir":
                strFavoriteColor = "Abi";
                break;
            case "Mahdi":
                strFavoriteColor = "Sabz";
                break;
            case "Meisam":
                strFavoriteColor = "Siah";
                break;
            case "Amin":
                strFavoriteColor = "zard";
                break;
            case "Reza":
                strFavoriteColor = "banafsh";
                break;

        }
        MessageBox.Show(strName + "'s favorite color is " + strFavoriteColor, "Select Demo");
```

what might be the issue?

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong, give the variable a default value: `string strFavoriteColor= string.Empty;`

Comment: If there was no matching `case` what would the value of `strFavoriteColor` be?

Comment: thank you your offer is so good to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
string strFavoriteColor;
```

write

```
string strFavoriteColor = "";
```

You didnt initialize it and you might not get any matches in your switch statment.

Answer (score 2):

`strFavoriteColor` might not have been initialized when you use it in the expression that you pass to `MessageBox.Show()`.

You can remedy that with a default case in your switch statement.

```
switch (strName)
{
    case "Amir":
        strFavoriteColor = "Abi";
        break;
    case "Mahdi":
        strFavoriteColor = "Sabz";
        break;
    ....
    default:
        strFavoriteColor = "<unknown>";
        break;
}
MessageBox.Show(...); // now strFavoriteColor has definitely been initialized
```